# Chrome ios - iframe: window.open doesn't work with onload handler

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, onload, window.open

Using Chrome for iOs in an iframe window.open doesn't work with onload handler but:
 - It works with chrome for other platform (android and windows).
 - It works if I put the method in onclick on a button

Following the code:

```
<INPUT type=button class=buttonStdWidth name=cbinvia value='#MSG('bok')' onclick=window.open("mypage",name,feat);>
```

Works!

```
<BODY onload=window.open("mypage",name,feat);>
```

Doesn't work!

Thanks

Comment: Where are the quotes in your attributes??

Comment: Is variables 'name' and 'feat' defined on document loaded state?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest handling the opening in a separate javascript function. Note that the javascript is in the  section, otherwise it isn't found.

```
<head>
    <script>

        function open_win(webaddress, name, feat)
        {
            window.open(webaddress, name, feat);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="open_win('http://www.google.com', 'myName', 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes')">

</body>
```